# Spark parallel execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to follow a code to concurrently execute spark jobs but I am not able to understand this part of the code
**implicit context: Context** in the function executeAndSave in below code and **what I need to import in Intellij because the existing imports are not able get it**

```scala
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, MINUTES}
  import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
  
  val pathPrefix = "/lake/mutlithreading/"
  val queries = Seq("SELECT * FROM ABC|output1",
                    "SELECT * FROM PQR|output2",
                    "SELECT * FROM XYZ|output3")
  val futureArray = new Array[Future[Unit]](3)
  var i = 0
  queries.foreach(queryAndPath => {
    val query = queryAndPath.split("\\|")(0)
    val dataPath = pathPrefix+queryAndPath.split("\\|")(1).trim
    futureArray(i) = Future {
      executeAndSave(query,dataPath)
    }
    i = i + 1
  })
  futureArray.map(s => Await.result(s, Duration(15, MINUTES)))
     
  def executeAndSave(query: String, dataPath: String)(implicit context: Context): Unit = {
    println(s"$query starts")
    context.spark.sql(query).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(dataPath)
    println(s"$query completes")
  }
```

This is example in medium The link for the same is:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/boosting-apache-spark-application-by-running-multiple-parallel-jobs-25d13ee7d2a6

Comment: 1) Parallelism and concurrency/asynchrony aren't the same thing.  2) The implicit should be able to resolve the global execution instance in `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` 3) What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Probably it should be SparkContext instead of Context. You can create it like that: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#initializing-spark

But actually your link does not seems like a good example of Scala code. it's seems reverse. So it's better to search an another sources for a parallel jobs. I think Spark do it parallel by design, always.

Comment: @sinanspd I am using Scala 2.11.8

Comment: @MikhailIonkin. My objective is to concurrently execute multiple Spark sql commands using this. I have spark sqls which are running sequentially I want avoid that